# React.Js Router Keycloak refreshing issue

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, react-router-dom

I have started using stack as mentioned in the topic, by using this tutorial:

https://cagline.medium.com/authenticate-and-authorize-react-routes-component-with-keycloak-666e85662636

Problem is that every time when I enter some page, by using menu webapp is refreshing, and loading keycloak again. Of course it keeps somewhere tokens so I dont need to login again, but I see this "Loading ... !!!" message everytime.

Is it possible somehow to avoid that ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally Ive found an answer, very good example is here
[springboot-react-keycloak](https://github.com/ivangfr/springboot-react-keycloak)